# Malloc space not accessible after another apparently indipendent function

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, scanf, fgets

I have a problem with malloc in the following change() function. When i = 5, when I read and trying to save the input line in s, the table[4] change and the debugger says: "<error: Cannot access memory at address 0xa696573>", even if before the value was correct. The same problem occurs using scanf instead of fgets or printing the table[3] value.

(I'm using `gcc -std=gnu11 -g` to compile and gdb for debugging in VS Code on Ubuntu in Linux subsystem in Windows 10)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **table;

int change()
{
    char s[1025];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        fgets(s, 1024, stdin);
        //scanf(" %1024[^\n]%*c", s);
        table[i] = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
        strcpy(table[i], s);
    }
}

int main()
{
    table = malloc(10);
    change();
    return 0;
}
```

[values before reading sixth (i=5) line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXRbw.png)

[values after reading sixth (i=5) line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F16C.png)

Comment: There's not enough here to see what you might be doing wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run.

Comment: Are you sure that's the real code, and *all* the code? `0xa696573` looks suspiciously like ASCII `\nies` (which is `sei\n` reversed) but that doesn't come from the posted code.

Comment: post the whole code .

Comment: Now I posted the all code, thanks for suggestion. It's my first question.

Comment: The ascii `sei\n` is from the input with which I tested the code

Comment: `table = malloc(10);` is wrong. Why `10`?

Comment: `table = malloc(10);` --> `table = malloc(sizeof *table * 7);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
table = malloc(10);
```

This allocates ten bytes of storage, which is not enough space for seven pointers (the loop in `change` cycles seven times). You should have something like `malloc(7 * sizeof(char *));` instead.

In the future, when you have bugs like these, try running the program under the [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org) debugging utility. In this case it would have told you plainly that you were writing past the end of the space allocated for `table`.

For reference, `sizeof(char *)` is almost always either four or eight.

Comment: Thank you vary much for the answer and for the suggestions, I'm feel so stupid...

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over it. This is an easy mistake to make. I know to look for it because I've done the same thing many times.